# Regular expression for Website address validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex, data-annotations

I have a user input to supply website address, obviously most users have no idea what is well formatted url so I look for a website address Regex that will follow this rules:

1) www.someaddress.com - **True**
2) someaddress.com - **True**
3) http://someaddress.com - **True**
4) https://someaddress.com - **True**
5) https://www.someaddress.co.il - **True**
6) http://www.someaddress.com - **True**

I use this **Regex**:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid website address")]
public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
```

But it's useless because it allows almost every string to pass.

Please supply a data annotation answer and not answers such as:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString
```

Because .net doesn't support client side validation for custom attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`UrlAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute) to validate URLs, but it does enforce the protocol being there, which it appears you don't want.

However, the source code is available and it does [use a regular expression](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs,46) that you can steal and modify. Modifying just the protocol portion to be optional the way you want, you get this:

```regex
^((http|ftp|https)://)?(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$
```

(Side note: I noticed that your regex allowed `www://`, which is suspicious. I took it out in this, but if you truly do need that, then you can add it.)

These are values I tested with:

```
www.someaddress.com             Yes
someaddress.com                 Yes
http://someaddress.com          Yes
https://someaddress.com         Yes
https://www.someaddress.co.il   Yes
cow                             No
hi hello.com                    No
this/that.com                   No
```

In the [comments of the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs,9) it does say:

> This attribute provides server-side url validation equivalent to jquery validate, and therefore shares the same regular expression.  See unit tests for examples.

Comment: Not to be a dick or anything, but the `www` in that group is wrong. It would accept `www://google.com`. Other than that, it is a damn nice regex.

Comment: @AndréSilva Yes, I took it from the regex in the question and I commented on it right under the regex in my answer :) It's not necessarily wrong, since you can make a custom protocol handler for anything (even [`web+burger:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers)) but it is suspicious.

Comment: Hahaha I love embarassing myself on SO comments. Damn.. Just now I noticed that I commented on the answer... I should read the questions more than once. Thanks for the heads up haha

Comment: Although, maybe I should remove it in case people find this later and blindly copy/paste.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I first used the `Url` data annotation but it includes the `http` part, +1 for the regex and the link for the source code :)